# Redirecting to localhost web app after successful login with IdenityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've just finished applying [this quickstart example from IdentityServer4 documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html). I currently have 3 apps: one for login (I will call it 'login page'), one being webapi endpoint and one being javascript SPA (single page application).

If one of webapi endpoints requires user to be authenticated, it informs SPA app about it. SPA app, then, redirects me to login page which I've recently deployed to internet.

Now, [this configuration](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html#add-a-client-registration-to-identityserver-for-the-javascript-client):

```
            // JavaScript Client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "js",
                ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                RedirectUris =           {
                    "http://localhost:5003/auth-callback",
                    "http://localhost:5003/assets/silent-refresh.html"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:5003" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                }
            }
```

works well as long as login page is functioning in localhost.

Now I deployed login page to internet. That means that after successful login, it will try to redirect user to:

> http://localhost:5003/auth-callback

which won't work as it's local, not accessible from internet URL.

Now, keeping in mind that I need to locally test SPA apps: how can I configure IdentityServer4, so I could test my apps locally, but using identity provider placed in internet?

Comment: Have you tried using a *relative* URL?

Comment: How? Changing `RedirectUris` to for example: "/auth-callback" instead of "http://localhost:5003/auth-callback" causes "Invalid redirect_uri" error

Comment: The given example from the docs is just an example. In real world application you want to add new clients via an UI not as application seeding, since its a stupid idea to store credentials within the executable file. You need to add **A NEW CLIENT** for your production app and use it's client ID when authenticating.

Comment: A reason behind that is security, so an attacker can't just use your client id (and secret) and have users authenticate on his system, because he will be redirected back to the real website configured in idsrv4, so attacker can't phishing for tokens by letting user authenticate and return back to his own server

Comment: @Tseng an alternative for using a UI and adding clients dynamically could be persisting their list in appsettings.json (if the list would be more or less static).

Comment: Are there any examples of how it would be implemented in real life? Because I'm a bit confused now